# Session not starting on Cakephp 2.2.3

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I'm having a strange issue with sessions on cakephp 2.2.3... my sessions are not starting on the webserver. I tried to use this code on a controller:

```
<?php
 if ($this->Session->write('Test', 'hi')){
       echo $this->Session->read('Test');
  }
  else{
       echo 'bye';
  }
```

and the output was **bye** on webserver, and **hi** on localhost.

So, I checked further, and found that the method CakeSession::start() is always returning false. This started to happens today, and i couldn't realize what may be causing this...
my session configuration on core.php is

```
    Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'database',
    'checkAgent' => true,
    'timeout' => 31104000,
    'cookie' => 'vejomun'
));
```

When setting debug to 2, I receive a lot of warnings like this:

```
Warning (2): ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php, line 484]
```

but it has always been like this, and the sessions was ok untill yesterday...

thanks in advance, and sorry for bad english.

EDIT:

if anyone has the same problem, it was just an blank line at the begin of the html.

Comment: You should be getting the typical *headers already sent* error message. If you don't, you need to configure your PHP installation to display all error messages. (Voting to close since the question turned out invalid.)

Comment: -1 until you put your edit in an answer and accept it =)

Comment: I did it before I edited the question, but the answer was deleted...

Answer (score 0):

at the top of page write

```
    session_start();
```

if you write this line then and then php will compatible with session